# How to return HtmlDocument from WebBrowser using async in F#?

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I'm trying to scrape a series of websites that run a bunch of javascript on the DOM before it's done loading. This means I'm using a `WebBrowser` instead of the friendlier `WebClient`. The problem I'd like to solve is to wait until the `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event fires and then return `WebBrowser.Document`. I then do some post processing on the `HtmlDocument` but cannot get it to return yet.

### The Code I Have

```
let downloadWebSite (address : string) = 
    let browser = new WebBrowser()
    let browserContext = SynchronizationContext()
    browser.DocumentCompleted.Add (fun _ ->
        printfn "Document Loaded")

    async {
        do browser.Navigate(address)
        let! a = Async.AwaitEvent browser.DocumentCompleted
        do! Async.SwitchToContext(browserContext)
        return browser.Document)
    }


[downloadWebSite "https://www.google.com"]
|> Async.Parallel // there will be more addresses when working
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

### The Error

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IHTMLDocument2.GetLocation()
   at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.get_Document()
   at FSI_0058.downloadWebSite@209-41.Invoke(Unit _arg2) in C:\Temp\Untitled-1.fsx:line 209
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.CallThenInvokeNoHijackCheck[a,b](AsyncActivation`1 ctxt, FSharpFunc`2 userCode, b result1)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.Trampoline.Execute(FSharpFunc`2 firstAction)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncResult`1.Commit()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.RunSynchronouslyInAnotherThread[a](CancellationToken token, FSharpAsync`1 computation, FSharpOption`1 timeout)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.RunSynchronously[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken, FSharpAsync`1 computation, FSharpOption`1 timeout)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync.RunSynchronously[T](FSharpAsync`1 computation, FSharpOption`1 timeout, FSharpOption`1 cancellationToken)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0058>.$FSI_0058.main@()
Stopped due to error
```

### What I think is happening

There are several issues that make me believe that I'm accessing the `WebBrowser` from the wrong thread.[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559930/webbrowser-document-throws-specified-cast-is-not-valid-exception) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566337/specified-cast-is-not-valid-error) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590982/f-cross-thread-ui-exception-in-winforms-app)

### Help requested

- Is the use of `Async.SwitchToContext(browserContext)` correct here?
- Could the overall approach be simplified?
- Is there a concept I appear ignorant of?
- How do I get the `WebBrowser.Document`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
let browserContext = SynchronizationContext()
```

You manually created a new instance of `SynchronizationContext` but didn't associate it with the UI thread or any thread. That's why the program crashes when you access the `browser.Document` which must be accessed on the UI thread.

To solve this problem, simply use the existing `SynchronizationContext` which was already associated with the UI thread:

```
let browserContext = SynchronizationContext.Current
```

*I assumed that the `downloadWebSite` function is called on the UI thread. If it is not, you can pass the context from somewhere into the function, or use a global variable.*

#### A better design

Althought with `Async.SwitchToContext` you can make sure that the next line accesses and returns the document in the UI thread, but the client code which receives the document may run on a non-UI thread. A better design is to use a *continuation function*. Instead of directly returning a document, you can return a `SomeType` value produced by a continuation function passed into `downloadWebSite` as a parameter. By this way, the continuation function is ensured to be run on UI thread:

```
let downloadWebSite (address : string) cont =
    let browser = new WebBrowser()
    let browserContext = SynchronizationContext.Current
    browser.DocumentCompleted.Add (fun _ ->
        printfn "Document Loaded")

    async {
        do browser.Navigate(address)
        let! a = Async.AwaitEvent browser.DocumentCompleted
        do! Async.SwitchToContext(browserContext)
        // the cont function is ensured to be run on UI thread:
        return cont browser.Document }

[downloadWebSite "https://www.google.com" (fun document -> (*safely access document*))]
|> Async.Parallel
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: Did you get this to return? I put a print line below the `let!` statement and the print goes to console but it doesn't return. I think my machine is hanging on the `do! Async.SwitchToContext` line.